# python/django admin database website missing input fields

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to create a table in the database for the website.

I believe the table actually exists, but for some reason the variables don't?
[image]

Here is the relevant code. I don't think I've made any errors, but I must have somewhere?

```
#models.py
from django.db import models

Blockquote

# Create your models here.
class Feature(models.Model):
    name: models.CharField(max_length=100)
    details: models.CharField(max_length=200)
    is_true: models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

```
#admin.py
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Feature

# Register your models here.
admin.site.register(Feature)
```

settings.py file

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'myapp',#this adds your 'myapp' into your main project before you can start integrating into your main project.
]
```

**I've tried:**

- python manage.py makemigrations
- python manage.py migrate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not **assigning the variables**, but you're using type hints, which python basically just discards.

It should be written like:

```
class Feature(models.Model):
    name= models.CharField(max_length=100)
    details= models.CharField(max_length=200)
    is_true= models.BooleanField(default=False)
```